# Symfony 5.2.3 interface type-hinting

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, type-hinting, symfony5

Since I updated my `composer.json` (I just switched `symfony`, `console`, `dotenv`, `framework-bundle`, `yaml` versions from `"5.0.*` to,`"5.2.*`), I have this error:

`syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)` coming from line 27, file `vendor/psr/link/src/EvolvableLinkInterface.php`.

(`public function withHref(string|\Stringable $href);`)

I decided to remove one of my facultative parameter type hint (eg. `\Stringable`) and it worked well.

I'm running under `PHP 7.4.15`.

Do you know how could I fixed it?

Comment: Please share more details - the latest version of `psr/link` that is compatible with PHP 7 (which is verson 1.0.0) does not contain such a type hint. In v1.1.0 (which is **not** compatible with PHP 7), this type hint is present

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase! You're right. If I check my `psr/link` version in `InstalledVersions.php` I can see `1.1.0` which isn't compatible with my PHP version.
Two quick questions then: Why was it working before my `composer.json` changes?
How to fix the `psr/link` version (which doesn't appear in my `composer.json`)

Comment: That depends on which PHP version you require in  `composer.json`, and how you call it

Comment: @NicoHaase `"php": "^7.4"`

Comment: And how did you instruct composer to fetch new dependencies?

Comment: `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` and `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` (ignore flags to avoid newrelic dependency)

Comment: Well, yeah. Please have a look at the documentation about the meaning of `--ignore-platform-reqs` ;)

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase, I added `"psr/link": "1.0.*"` in my `composer.json` to force version 1.0.0 and it works perfectly. :)

Comment: And yes, I will have a look at the documentation!

Comment: You don't even need that requirement

Comment: Okay, I will check the documentation right now then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that our good buddies at https://github.com/php-fig jumped the gun with using [Union Type Hints](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.union) which is only available with php8. They did not provide support for php7. They went from php5 to php8 for some reason. You can see this in packagist:

[psr/link v1.0.0](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/link#1.0.0) vs [psr/link v1.1.0](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/link#1.1.0)

Also in:

[psr/log v1.1.4](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/log#1.1.4) vs [psr/log v2.0.0](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/log#2.0.0)

This is causing issues also in Laravel 7 that relies on psr/log and running php7.

You will need to specify an older package versions:

`composer require psr/link "1.0.*"`

`composer require psr/log "^1.0"`

Comment: This is actually what I've done, I specified an older version. Thanks for the details.